# iPhone Realtime Image Processing using OpenCV and AVFoundation Frameworks?

Tags: iphone, image-processing, opencv, avfoundation

I want to doing image processing in real time by using openCV.

My final target is showing the result in realtime on the screen while the other side camera is capturing the video by using AVFoundation frameworks.

How can I process every video frame by OpenCV, and show the result on the screen in real time?

Comment: As it stands, this question is too broad to answer.  What part of the process do you need help with: grabbing the video frames with AVFoundation, compiling and using OpenCV on iPhone, or displaying an overlaid image?  What are you trying to recognize using OpenCV?

Answer (score 2):

Use AVAssertReader

```
//Setup Reader
   AVURLAsset * asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:urlvalue options:nil]; 
    [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tracks"] completionHandler: ^{ dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        AVAssetTrack * videoTrack = nil; 
        NSArray * tracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if ([tracks count] == 1) {
            videoTrack = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];
            NSError * error = nil; 
            _movieReader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:asset error:&error]; 
            if (error) 
                NSLog(error.localizedDescription); 
            NSString* key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey; 
            NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_4444AYpCbCr16]; NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key];
            [_movieReader addOutput:[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:videoTrack outputSettings:videoSettings]]; 
             [_movieReader startReading];

        } 
    }); 
    }];
```

to get next movie frame

```
static int frameCount=0;
- (void) readNextMovieFrame { 

    if (_movieReader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusReading) { 

        AVAssetReaderTrackOutput * output = [_movieReader.outputs objectAtIndex:0]; 
        CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [output copyNextSampleBuffer];
        if (sampleBuffer) {
            CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
            // Lock the image buffer 
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
            // Get information of the image 
            uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 
            size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
            size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
            size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 

            /*We unlock the  image buffer*/
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

            /*Create a CGImageRef from the CVImageBufferRef*/
             CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 
            CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 
            CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext); 

            /*We release some components*/
            CGContextRelease(newContext); 
            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

            /*We display the result on the custom layer*/
            /*self.customLayer.contents = (id) newImage;*/

            /*We display the result on the image view (We need to change the orientation of the image so that the video is displayed correctly)*/
            UIImage *image= [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:0.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

            [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

           // UIImage *img=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            videoImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


//videoImage=image;

          //  if (frameCount < 40) {
                NSLog(@"readNextMovieFrame==%d",frameCount);
                      NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/frame_%d.png", frameCount];
                      NSString* pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
                     [UIImagePNGRepresentation(videoImage) writeToFile: pngPath atomically: YES];
                     frameCount++;
        //        }

            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0); 
            CFRelease(sampleBuffer); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

once your _movieReader reach end then you need to restart again.